# Can scala implicitly join 2 implicits into an implicit tuple?

Tags: scala, tuples, implicit

**Context:**
I am trying to work with Java's RandomAccessFile, and I want to be able to read/write anything with an implicit `fixedBytable`:

```scala
case class FixedBytable[T](private val size: Int,
                           private val read: ByteBuffer => T,
                           private val write: (T, ByteBuffer) => Unit)
```

I defined `FixedBytable` for all the basic `byte`/`short`/`float`/`...`, which works just fine. I was also able to define tuple_Bytable for all the tuple types, which can join 2 (or whatever sized tuple) `FixedBytable` into 1, that can read/write a tuple of the "children" (ex: `FixedBytable[(Int, Int)]`.

**Question:**
Can you do this implicitly? Maybe I am phrasing this wrong, but is there a way to say that if you can implicitly find a `FixedByable[A]` and a `FixedBytable[B]`, then you should know how to implicitly find a `FixedBytable[(A, B)]`?

Comment: Yes, you can start with something like: `ìmplicit def tupleFixedByable[A, B](implicit aFB: FixedByable[A], bFB: FixedByable[B]): FixedByable[(A, B)] =` you need to provide the logic to create the instance for the tuple, but this should get what you want.

Comment: Awesome! That worked, thanks! I had it so close, I was just missing the implicit inside the parens.

Comment: great! I invite you to answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to get my problem to work, hopefully you can abstract it away to whatever your situation is.
The key here is that you need both the `implicit def`, and an `implicit` at the start of the parameters.

```scala
/*
Note:
implicit def
implicit b1: ...
*/

implicit def tuple2Bytable[T1, T2](implicit b1: Bytable[T1], b2: Bytable[T2]): Bytable[(T1, T2)] =
  Bytable[(T1, T2)](
    b1.size + b2.size,
    bb => {
      val v1: T1 = b1.fromBytes(bb)
      val v2: T2 = b2.fromBytes(bb)
      (v1, v2)
    },
    (t, bb) => {
      b1.toBytes(t._1, bb)
      b2.toBytes(t._2, bb)
    }
  )

implicit def tuple3Bytable[T1, T2, T3](implicit b1: Bytable[T1], b2: Bytable[T2], b3: Bytable[T3]): Bytable[(T1, T2, T3)] =
  Bytable[(T1, T2, T3)](
    b1.size + b2.size + b3.size,
    bb => {
      val v1: T1 = b1.fromBytes(bb)
      val v2: T2 = b2.fromBytes(bb)
      val v3: T3 = b3.fromBytes(bb)
      (v1, v2, v3)
    },
    (t, bb) => {
      b1.toBytes(t._1, bb)
      b2.toBytes(t._2, bb)
      b3.toBytes(t._3, bb)
    }
  )
```